# Youtube embedded videos unavailable

Tags: embed, videos

Three days ago all the embedded videos were working perfectly. Now some of them work but most show the message "Video unavailable" and a link to watch it on YouTube.

On debug info, I receive this:

```
{
   "errorCode":"auth",
   "errorDetail":"0",
   "errorMessage":"Vídeo indisponível",
   "Zm":"",
   "bK":"0;a6s.0",
   "BH":2,
   "cpn":"Qa4z19Im4j9VMjM6"
}
```

I think this is the important part of the debug info. If you guys need some other information please ask.

WordPress Version:  6.4.1

Theme: Newspaper (from TagDiv)

Active Plugins list:

- AdRotate Banner Manager
- Contact Form 7
- Easy Table of Contents
- Inline Related Posts
- Site Kit by Google
- tagDiv Cloud Library
- tagDiv Composer
- tagDiv Opt-In Builder
- tagDiv Social Counter
- tagDiv Standard Pack
- Wordfence Security
- WP Mail SMTP
- WP Rocket
- Yoast SEO
- Yoast SEO: News
- Yoast SEO Premium
- Yoast Test Helper